# invalid console appender config detected because of WSS4JOutInterceptor

Tags: java, log4j, cxf

I have the following problem.
`invalid console appender config detected, console stream is looping`

I am running a cxf servlet 2.2.10 on a JBoss 5.1 AS.

The problem is being caused by a log4j jar or class in certain dependencies like commons-logging and log4j.jar. With maven I can exclude these dependencies and the error goes away.

But my next task in this project is to include an

`org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor`

This requires cxf-rt-ws-security. With that jar an indirect dependency: cxf-common-utilities tags along.

That jar has a lot of needed classes but also one annoying log4Logger.

Thus, because of that jar I now get the same

`invalid console appender config detected, console stream is looping`

My appender config:
`appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender"`

#### Update:

My conf is located in the conf folder on jboss in the file jboss-log4j.xml.

Comment: Where is your appender config situated?
In a log4j.properties file inside your project? Or in the jboss-log4j.xml

Comment: My conf is located in the conf folder on jboss in the file jboss-log4j.xml.

Answer (score 4):

The java option referenced in the abhijava blogspot entry worked for me. Presumably this is a config conflict and this just overrides the error, but nevertheless it is good enough for now. Thanks all!

set JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.jboss.logging.Log4jService.catchSystemOut=false

Answer (score 0):

Can this link help you?
http://raykrueger.blogspot.com/2007/01/jboss-console-stream-is-looping-error.html

I'm not able to try and reproduce the problem at this time. Perhaps I can try to generate a small project at home.
Can you give me some more information what I have to setup and to do to create a project like yours and how to reproduce the error?

And be sure to check there's only one ConsoleAppender configured:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/logging/util/LoggerStream.java.html
/* There is a configuration error that is causing looping. Most
   likely there are two console appenders so just return to prevent
   spinning.
*/

Comment: I have only 1 console appender, but 2 daily rolling file appenders. This produces no error and works fine if only the logging jars of JBoss are used. The setup is spring 3 and cxf 2.2.10

Answer (score 0):

Another link that specifies the same problem:
http://abhijava.blogspot.com/2010/10/log4j-jboss-and-application-conflict.html

Comment: I have only one console appender.